# Setting Date on Android device works from settings menu but requires root access via ADB (which I do not have)

Tags: android, shell, datetime, adb, root

If not manually set, the date and time of the Pico G2 4K headset is never correct. I'm attempting to set it via the command line like this:

```
adb shell "toybox date 110309162023.14"
```

and finding that root access is required, however when I enter the developer settings menu in the headset, I can change the date and time with no issue. Is there something I'm missing or a different command I should be trying?

I've tried searching the Pico XR documentation, as well as issuing a similar commands like `adb shell toolbox date <datestring>` and `adb shell date <datestring>` as well as searching stackoverflow for similar questions. So far nothing has worked.

Thanks in advance for any guidance with this!

Comment: Settings app is a system app with special permissions therefore it can do what no other app or adb can do.

Comment: Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code problems. Your question seems more appropriate for [androrid.se]. Please delete here and repost there. Good luck.